# What is this insect found in Western Arkansas?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I had my cup of water outside with me, went inside for a few minutes, came back outside and this insect almost found out what was unpleasant about being drunk.

It's 1-2cm long, mostly black, with some white spots on the back. The bottom of the abdomen was also white/gray & black striped.

What did I almost drink?
[image: Almost discovered what's so unpleasant about being drunk]
[image: coin in the bottom of the cup for scale]

**Update:**
I saw another one of these at the park - it's rear legs were positioned [like a stink bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_marmorated_stink_bug), and before I could take any pictures of it, it flew off. It had a sustained flight, like a wasp, rather than say a grasshopper.

Comment: A better close-up, something for scale, and a photo of the underside would be helpful...

Comment: @arboviral I've added another pic of the cup with a US quarter, since the bug is long gone. The bug was roughly the same size.

Comment: That sure looks an awful lot like a cricket.

Comment: I've never seen a cricket like that. It was skinnier/longer than a cricket, and I *think* it may have had wings (though I could be wrong on that). You can kind of see the two white "L" shaped spots on the back - they were quite white IRL.

Comment: It could be Gryllus pennsylvanicus.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh No, that's definitely not it. I've got plenty of crickets and I know them. I actually have two in front of me waiting on my jumping spider to consume them. I actually saw another one of these guys later on at a park but before I could snap a picture it *flew off*. One thing I noticed was that one that wasn't in my water cup held its bag legs [like a stink bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_marmorated_stink_bug#/media/File:Brown_marmorated_stink_bug.jpg) - that distinctive splayed style.

Comment: I see. So you are an insect keeper :) . Today somebody asked a question about identification of a cricket and  Gryllus pennsylvanicus was the one, and your insect too looked similar, so I thought I might tell you.

Comment: Your comment got me looking again and I found this [eastern leaf-footed bug](http://bugguide.net/node/view/437) that's *very* similar. The distinction I see - it's not a straight white bar on the back, and the hind legs aren't "leafy".

Comment: Zooming in on the photo showed me an antenna with more than five segments, so definitely not a true bug (and the segmentation being almost clear eliminates crickets as well); the same zoom also showed what seem to me to be short elytra (the front wings of a beetle).  Not knowing where the photo was taken (beyond probably the United States, unless Wayne also collects foreign coins?) forbids me from speculating further.

Comment: @ArthurJFrost Western Arkansas

Comment: That is not a true bug.  It looks like a beetle, possibly in the group that includes the borers.  Exactly what it might be, though, I don't know.  I've seen that sort of hind leg position before, and noticed it, but I'm darned if I can recall in what.